# MIxed Model Ordinal Regression Drops Random Intercepts

Tags: mixed-model, ordinal-data, polr

Please could you help me?

I have been trying for quite some time to fit a mixed model with multiple binary and continuous predictors and an ordinal dependent variable. Subject ID defines the random intercepts.

I have more than 3053 observations from 176 subjects in two main conditions (dreams and mindwandering; for which I use an interaction). These 176 individuals have different numbers of repetitions for each condition. Some have some observations in one condition but none in the other and viceversa. Either way, the number of observations differ between individuals.
I reduced the independent variables due to high multicollinearity (PC1 and PC2 below) and kept the independent variables that have correlations r>0.5.
I have tried to run the model using MASS::polr, Ordinal::CLMM, CLMM2, as well as BRMS::brm (the latter now throws strange and not so reproducible errors).
this is what the model looks like (polr example)

```
model_clin_PHQ <- polr(PHQ_O ~  scale(Word_Count_log)*DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)*DREAM_MW+Gender+ scale(NET_Assort)*DREAM_MW+ scale(PC1)*DREAM_MW + scale(PC2)*DREAM_MW+ scale(NET_Clust_log)*DREAM_MW +scale(AGE)+COUNTRY+ (1| P_ID), data = dat_without_outlier, Hess=TRUE)
```

In this “DREAM_MW” is an important condition for which I check interactions,
P_ID is the numeric subject ID. Country and GENDER are binary variables and the rest continuous.
The other models are defined in a very similar manner to this.
My objective is to estimate a reliable model with p-values (I am afraid this is the status quo of this type of research).
For this model I get "**design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs**"
The output:

```
polr(formula = PHQ_O ~ scale(Word_Count_log) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) * 
    DREAM_MW + Gender + scale(NET_Assort) * DREAM_MW + scale(PC1) * 
    DREAM_MW + scale(PC2) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Clust_log) * 
    DREAM_MW + scale(AGE) + COUNTRY + (1 | P_ID), data = dat_without_outlier, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                                        Value Std. Error   t value
scale(Word_Count_log)               -0.025063    0.04644  -0.53965
DREAM_MWMW                           0.164164    0.07362   2.22983
scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)             0.112437    0.04758   2.36299
Gender                              -0.184038    0.08433  -2.18226
scale(NET_Assort)                   -0.042983    0.04784  -0.89842
scale(PC1)                          -0.251628    0.06049  -4.15990
scale(PC2)                          -0.035111    0.05233  -0.67090
scale(NET_Clust_log)                 0.031515    0.05282   0.59665
scale(AGE)                          -0.388714    0.03721 -10.44784
COUNTRY                             -0.434912    0.07259  -5.99123
scale(Word_Count_log):DREAM_MWMW    -0.047547    0.07123  -0.66748
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) -0.189531    0.07220  -2.62514
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Assort)         0.187682    0.07542   2.48857
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC1)                0.138605    0.08696   1.59397
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC2)                0.004897    0.07379   0.06636
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Clust_log)     -0.070019    0.08035  -0.87138

Intercepts:
                         Value    Std. Error t value 
none|mild                 -0.9443   0.1052    -8.9725
mild|moderate              0.9379   0.1062     8.8319
moderate|moderate-severe   2.8388   0.1303    21.7899
moderate-severe|severe     3.4833   0.1519    22.9272

scale(Word_Count_log)               -0.0250629  0.0464430  -0.5396  0.589439    
DREAM_MWMW                           0.1641637  0.0736215   2.2298  0.025758 *  
scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)             0.1124366  0.0475822   2.3630  0.018128 *  
Gender                              -0.1840378  0.0843336  -2.1823  0.029090 *  
scale(NET_Assort)                   -0.0429829  0.0478429  -0.8984  0.368963    
scale(PC1)                          -0.2516276  0.0604888  -4.1599 3.184e-05 ***
scale(PC2)                          -0.0351112  0.0523344  -0.6709  0.502283    
scale(NET_Clust_log)                 0.0315150  0.0528204   0.5966  0.550744    
scale(AGE)                          -0.3887137  0.0372052 -10.4478 < 2.2e-16 ***
COUNTRY                             -0.4349121  0.0725915  -5.9912 2.083e-09 ***
scale(Word_Count_log):DREAM_MWMW    -0.0475474  0.0712342  -0.6675  0.504465    
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) -0.1895313  0.0721986  -2.6251  0.008661 ** 
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Assort)         0.1876816  0.0754173   2.4886  0.012826 *  
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC1)                0.1386055  0.0869563   1.5940  0.110943    
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC2)                0.0048973  0.0737949   0.0664  0.947088    
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Clust_log)     -0.0700186  0.0803538  -0.8714  0.383548    
none|mild                           -0.9443208  0.1052461  -8.9725 < 2.2e-16 ***
mild|moderate                        0.9379082  0.1061958   8.8319 < 2.2e-16 ***
moderate|moderate-severe             2.8388152  0.1302811  21.7899 < 2.2e-16 ***
moderate-severe|severe               3.4832630  0.1519271  22.9272 < 2.2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
```

Of note is that there is no estimate of the intercepts in the coefficients. In fact, Even if I remove all predictors and use only 1|P_ID I still get the same warning.
Thus I am inclined to believe that the intercepts is what is causing the model to be rank deficient.
Would you trust this model even though the random intercepts have been dropped?

When I run the model with CLMM I get

```
Cumulative Link Mixed Model fitted with the Laplace approximation

formula: PHQ_O ~ scale(Word_Count_log) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) *  
    DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Assort) * DREAM_MW + scale(PC1) * DREAM_MW +  
    scale(PC2) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Clust_log) * DREAM_MW +  
    scale(AGE) + COUNTRY + Gender + (1 | P_ID)
data:    dat_without_outlier


Random effects:
 Groups Name        Variance Std.Dev.
 P_ID   (Intercept) 14242    119.3   
Number of groups:  P_ID 176 

Coefficients:
                                      Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
scale(Word_Count_log)                0.0006250  1.0554870   0.001    1.000
DREAM_MWMW                           0.0078514  1.6572566   0.005    0.996
scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)            -0.0039393  1.0790258  -0.004    0.997
scale(NET_Assort)                   -0.0554854  1.0835674  -0.051    0.959
scale(PC1)                          -0.1251549  1.3783526  -0.091    0.928
scale(PC2)                           0.0334129  1.1994965   0.028    0.978
scale(NET_Clust_log)                 0.0452586  1.1606962   0.039    0.969
scale(AGE)                          -0.6171506  1.1746190  -0.525    0.599
COUNTRY                             -0.6033784  2.2255824  -0.271    0.786
Gender                               1.5192000  2.2200040   0.684    0.494
scale(Word_Count_log):DREAM_MWMW    -0.0008618  1.5325793  -0.001    1.000
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) -0.0259943  1.6040602  -0.016    0.987
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Assort)         0.1917768  1.6785488   0.114    0.909
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC1)                0.0550844  1.9661386   0.028    0.978
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC2)               -0.0819698  1.6194986  -0.051    0.960
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Clust_log)     -0.0825658  1.7257390  -0.048    0.962

Threshold coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value
mild|moderate     17.963      3.552   5.057
moderate|severe   42.162      4.003  10.533
```

Here there are no significant variables (note I have not tested assumptions for this), thus in contradiction with all the other models. Still no intercept.
With CLMM2 instead I get a rank deficient warning.

```
Warning: **design appears to be rank-deficient, so dropping some coefs**

Call:
clm2(location = PHQ_O ~ scale(Word_Count_log) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr) * 
    DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Assort) * DREAM_MW + scale(PC1) * DREAM_MW + 
    scale(PC2) * DREAM_MW + scale(NET_Clust_log) * DREAM_MW + 
    scale(AGE) + COUNTRY + Gender + (1 | P_ID), data = dat_without_outlier)

Location coefficients:
                                    Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)  
scale(Word_Count_log)                 0.0274   0.0620     0.4428 0.65788451
DREAM_MWMW                            0.1717   0.1017     1.6886 0.09130061
scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)              0.0462   0.0642     0.7187 0.47230257
scale(NET_Assort)                    -0.1091   0.0672    -1.6243 0.10432032
scale(PC1)                           -0.2310   0.0877    -2.6342 0.00843454
scale(PC2)                            0.0980   0.0739     1.3262 0.18478429
scale(NET_Clust_log)                  0.0712   0.0714     0.9971 0.31874001
scale(AGE)                           -0.5953   0.0523   -11.3840 < 2.22e-16
COUNTRY                              -0.7996   0.0917    -8.7226 < 2.22e-16
Gender                                0.6361   0.1206     5.2741 1.3339e-07
scale(Word_Count_log):DREAM_MWMW     -0.0831   0.0928    -0.8958 0.37036683
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Max_BetwCentr)  -0.0635   0.0966    -0.6575 0.51085338
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Assort)          0.3392   0.1011     3.3562 0.00079032
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC1)                 0.0647   0.1205     0.5372 0.59113752
DREAM_MWMW:scale(PC2)                -0.2401   0.1000    -2.4010 0.01635050
DREAM_MWMW:scale(NET_Clust_log)      -0.1932   0.1087    -1.7770 0.07556288

No scale coefficients

Threshold coefficients:
                Estimate Std. Error z value 
mild|moderate     1.6396   0.1470    11.1552
moderate|severe   3.6133   0.1687    21.4170

log-likelihood: -1793.083 
AIC: 3622.165 
Condition number of Hessian: 80.26572
```

Still no intercept but at least similar results to POLR
An alternative is to run the model with averaged values per each participant (thus removing the need to have random effects defined but also reducing statistical power [?]).
Here I get no errors but completely different results which is quite discouraging. Why might this be? Would you trust these results given the difference between the approaches?

```
Call:
polr(formula = PHQ_O ~ Word_Count_log_Dream + Word_Count_log_MW + 
    NET_Max_BetwCentr_Dream + NET_Max_BetwCentr_MW + NET_Assort_Dream + 
    NET_Assort_MW + PC1_Dream + PC1_MW + PC2_Dream + PC2_MW + 
    NET_Clust_log_Dream + NET_Clust_log_MW + COUNTRY, data = dat_NoRand, 
    control = c(maxit = 1e+05, trace = 0), na.action = na.omit, 
    Hess = TRUE)

Coefficients:
                           Value Std. Error  t value
Word_Count_log_Dream     0.03329     0.1833  0.18168
Word_Count_log_MW       -0.07240     0.1861 -0.38902
NET_Max_BetwCentr_Dream  0.41708     0.1977  2.11004
NET_Max_BetwCentr_MW    -0.23394     0.1716 -1.36330
NET_Assort_Dream        -0.16045     0.2109 -0.76074
NET_Assort_MW            0.27102     0.2042  1.32698
PC1_Dream               -0.25567     0.2189 -1.16774
PC1_MW                  -0.28361     0.2539 -1.11694
PC2_Dream               -0.10281     0.1839 -0.55896
PC2_MW                   0.05536     0.1848  0.29953
NET_Clust_log_Dream      0.07895     0.1941  0.40665
NET_Clust_log_MW         0.01616     0.2192  0.07374
COUNTRY                 -0.51941     0.3505 -1.48187

Intercepts:
                         Value   Std. Error t value
none|mild                -0.9049  0.2985    -3.0314
mild|moderate             0.8907  0.2980     2.9888
moderate|moderate-severe  2.9225  0.4413     6.6228
moderate-severe|severe    3.5130  0.5483     6.4068

Residual Deviance: 346.9475 
AIC: 380.9475 
(28 observations deleted due to missingness)

z test of coefficients:

                          Estimate Std. Error z value  Pr(>|z|)    
Word_Count_log_Dream      0.033294   0.183256  0.1817  0.855834    
Word_Count_log_MW        -0.072396   0.186099 -0.3890  0.697262    
NET_Max_BetwCentr_Dream   0.417075   0.197663  2.1100  0.034855 *  
NET_Max_BetwCentr_MW     -0.233942   0.171599 -1.3633  0.172788    
NET_Assort_Dream         -0.160454   0.210918 -0.7607  0.446811    
NET_Assort_MW             0.271018   0.204237  1.3270  0.184517    
PC1_Dream                -0.255674   0.218948 -1.1677  0.242911    
PC1_MW                   -0.283614   0.253921 -1.1169  0.264021    
PC2_Dream                -0.102809   0.183928 -0.5590  0.576188    
PC2_MW                    0.055363   0.184831  0.2995  0.764532    
NET_Clust_log_Dream       0.078948   0.194145  0.4066  0.684267    
NET_Clust_log_MW          0.016160   0.219169  0.0737  0.941221    
COUNTRY                  -0.519406   0.350507 -1.4819  0.138374    
none|mild                -0.904885   0.298503 -3.0314  0.002434 ** 
mild|moderate             0.890692   0.298015  2.9888  0.002801 ** 
moderate|moderate-severe  2.922522   0.441279  6.6228 3.523e-11 ***
moderate-severe|severe    3.513019   0.548324  6.4068 1.486e-10 ***
---
```

My question is can I trust any of these models (in particular, I would like to use a mixed model)?
Secondly, what could I do to improve the situation? What would you do? Any suggestions welcome.
I am quite unsure of how to define the Bayesian prior so I have not tried this.
All the best
Thank you.